# Program makes a beep sound even though it doesn't contain \a anywhere

Tags: c, for-loop, ascii

My computer made a beep sound even though I did not add `\a` to my code. Why?

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define START_CHAR ' '
#define END_CHAR 'DEL'

int main(void)
{  /* This code prints characters on keyboard.*/

   /* declaration */

  int char_code;

  for (char_code=(int)START_CHAR; char_code<=(int)END_CHAR; char_code=char_code+1)
    printf("%c", (char)char_code);

  printf("\n");

  return(0); 
}
```

Comment: #offtopic: I wonder how this code only question got posted. Isn't there a filter to stop that?

Comment: @SouravGhosh hmm before you edited it was a bunch of text, wasn't it ? :) And yes, it should not be allowed.

Comment: `#define END_CHAR 'DEL'` --> `#define END_CHAR '~'`. Also, all those casts are not necessary.

Comment: `char_code=(int)START_CHAR`...why's the `(int)`?

Comment: On my PC, `printf("%d\n", (int)END_CHAR);` outputs `4474188`. So a large loop, and as you cast the `int` back to `char` the "alert" `\a` is going to sound quite a lot.

Comment: Why did you use `'DEL'` there? It's like using `'SPACE'` instead of `' '`, doesn't make any sense

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) for a list of valid escape sequences.

Comment: This code is a book sample so I don't know why int is used.Also I wanted to see all characters on keyboard that's why I write "DEL" apparently I read the last character wrong .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'DEL'` is not a valid character constant.  It ends up being equal to 4474188.  And since you have `char_code` defined as an `int`, the loop goes from 32 (the ASCII code for a space) to 4474188.  So it loops through the full character set multiple times.

You should be using `0x7F` instead.

Comment: Strictly speaking `'DEL'` is a valid character constant, but has an implementation-defined value. (K&R page 193 / C99 §6.4.4.4[10])